# Function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)| > |z|$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}, 1/f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ is a function such that $|f(z)| > |z|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$

How would you prove the function $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is bounded. I think you have to use the $|f(z)|\leq M$ but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, ${1\over {|f(z)|}}<1$ for $|z|>1$ since $B(0,1)$ is compact, ${1\over {|f(z)|}}$ is bounded on $B(0,1)$. This implies that ${1\over {|f(z)|}}$ is bounded.

Comment: Hey thank you, would it be a possible to explain the beginning steps a little bit maybe in more language like B(0,1) and the bits before that. I would really appreciate it

Comment: Since $|f(z)|>|z|>1$, we deduce that $1>{1\over{|z|}}>{1\over{|f(z)|}}$.

Comment: thank you so much, did you mean B[0,1] instead of B(0,1) also, how would I show that its compact. That would be so great if you could explain.